# What are the differences between a $\psi$-epistemic ontological model and a $\psi$-ontic model of quantum mechanics, exactly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-interpretations, determinism

I am confused about the differences between a $\psi$-epistemic ontological model of quantum mechanics and a $\psi$-ontic one.

The way I understand it, a $\psi$-epistemic model says that every quantum state does not correspond to a physical state, and I understand this is to be interpreted as saying that quantum mechanics isn't a complete description of reality.

However, I also understand that an ontological model assumes that there is a way to assign a complete (deterministic) description of reality, and this seems to point to a $\psi$-ontic model, if I get that one correctly.

Where am I going wrong here, and how exactly should one interpret these terms?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You seem to be rather confused regarding those terms. The terms $\psi$-epistemic and $\psi$-ontic are mutually exclusive when describing an interpretation of quantum mechanics.

Both of these terms are possible characteristics for an *ontological model*: a description of the set $\Lambda$ of possible "complete descriptions of reality", which are often denoted by $\lambda$ and termed *ontic states*.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In other words, an ontological model is a descriptions of the things that "exist" in the real world. On that stage, there are two types: $\psi$-ontic models, where the wavefunction "exists", and $\psi$-epistemic models, where it doesn't.

More concretely:

- In $\psi$-ontic models, the wavefunction is a physical property of the "real" state of the world. That is, if I were to obtain a complete description of reality for the state of the system, then I can deduce the wavefunction $\psi$ from this state. Graphically, such models look like this:

  [image: Mathematica graphics]

  Note, however, that this does not fully rule out interpretations of $\psi$ as a statistical quantity: it can still be a distribution over a set of real states, with each wavefunction corresponding to a distinct set of states.

  - As a subset of these models, if the real state of the system turns out to be fully informationally equivalent to the wavefunction, the model is called $\psi$-complete.

    [image: Mathematica graphics]

    In such a model, if I know the wavefunction, then I know all that there is to know about the system. This rules out e.g. hidden variables
- In $\psi$-epistemic models, the wavefunction is not a physical property, but rather a statistical quantity and really just a description of *our* state of knowledge about the system. More concretely, a model is called $\psi$-epistemic if it allows the existence of two different wavefunctions that are consistent with the same "real" state of the system.

  [image: Mathematica graphics]

  In particular, this means that you cannot deduce the wavefunction from the ontic state of the world.

In terms of how you phrased it in the question,

> [the way $\psi$-epistemic models should] be interpreted is that quantum mechanics isn't a complete description of reality,

that is correct but not quite there. In $\psi$-epistemic models QM isn't a complete description of reality, but that is also the case in $\psi$-ontic models that are not $\psi$-complete.

For more details, see the paper that (to my knowledge) introduced these terms with precise definitions:

> Einstein, incompleteness, and the epistemic view of quantum states. N Harrigan and RW Spekkens. [*Found. Phys.* **40**, 125 (2010)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10701-009-9347-0), [arXiv:0706.2661](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2661).

---

<sup>[image] Mathematica source for the graphics: Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtA9o.png"].</sup>

Comment: Related: [How can you be a realist and not posit an ontological model?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293441/how-can-you-be-a-realist-and-not-posit-an-ontological-model)