How can non-realism alone explain quantum entanglement?
I’ve seen similar questions on this site but haven’t found a clear answer for this question. For clarity, I’ll define how my layman brain is interpreting locality and realism…
Locality: Information cannot travel faster than light; causally linked events must happen locally.
Realism: Information is deterministic and not fundamentally random/probabilistic.
From these two properties, four possibilities are often presented:

Local realism
Local non-realism
Non-local realism
Non-local non-realism

Bell’s Inequality shows us that a local realism model cannot work. Therefore, point 1 Is ruled out. This makes sense to me. However, here’s what I don’t understand:
How can non-realism ALONE (point 2) explain what’s happening to entangled particles correlating over arbitrarily large distances? Let’s just assume we accept that non-realism is true, QM is fundamentally probabilistic, and particles have no defined state until measured. This alone doesn’t explain how measuring one particle causes a correlation with its pair far away. In my head, only points 3 & 4 can work. Point 2 doesn’t allow for the instantaneous correlation of both particles. Yet I read that most physicists prefer the local non-realism interpretation.
How is probability/randomness a possible interpretation for "spooky action at a distance"? What am I missing?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

After two recent questions on this (here's the other one), I felt it was time to write up a long account on why there are no “local non-realist” theories which can explain Bell Correlations.  (A few caveats below.)
The modern structure of Bell’s Theorem is a proof by contradiction, running as follows: 1) make certain precise assumptions, 2) from these assumptions, prove an inequality (say, CHSH) that can be expressed operationally, 3) notice an experimental violation of these inequalities, 4) conclude that at least one of the initial assumptions from (1) must be false in any model which can give the right results for these experiments.
Unfortunately, the package of assumptions from (1), as expressed in Bell’s later papers and other modern proofs (not [Bell, 1964]!), has somehow been associated with the phrase “local realism”.  Maybe it shouldn’t matter – it’s just words, after all – but it’s not the phrase that Bell used.  Bell used “local causality” or “locality” for short.  But the words “local realism” have taken on a life of their own, and confused far too many people (including some here) into thinking that the assumptions break down into “locality” and “realism”, and we can choose one of these to discard, independent of the other.  Well, let’s see.
(Here I’m following the notation in https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04313 , because it breaks out the controllable inputs into subscripts, and therefore explicitly prevents the crazy move of assigning probability distributions to Alice’s and Bob’s settings.  They can choose whatever settings they want, with any distribution whatsoever, of course.  We shouldn’t and can’t model Alice!)

Operational Variables:
$a$: Alice’s setting (in region 1)
$A$: Alice’s output (in region 1)
$b$: Bob’s setting (in region 2)
$B$: Bob’s output (in region 2)
$c$: Source preparation setting
Other variables:
$\lambda$: all variables associated with the spacetime region $\Lambda$ in the above figure. (These are not “operational” variables in that they can’t be directly observed.)
(Notice that $\lambda$ must be associated with this particular spacetime region, which implies that $\lambda$ is the sort of variable which can be a function over spacetime, like electric fields and particle positions.  It does not include wavefunctions, since wavefunctions do not have a general spacetime representation.  Multi-particle wavefunctions are functions in Hilbert or configuration space, not spacetime (x,y,z,t).)
Now, what does Bell’s Theorem attempt to restrict?  Models of entanglement.  Models which correctly predict the joint probability P(A,B) given any choice of inputs (a,b,c).  Since inputs are special (they don’t have probability distributions), I’ll write such a model using subscripts as inputs.  A model of these phenomena must, at minimum, generate a probability distribution of the outputs given any inputs, which I will write as just the probability distribution
$P_{a,b,c}(A,B)$ .
Obviously there are models which can do this correctly (say, quantum mechanics).  But can they do it in a “local” way?  To answer that, we need to define what we mean by locality.  Bell found a nice way to do that, simply by allowing for the possibility that a deeper-level model might also make predictions of $\lambda$ along with the outcomes $(A,B)$.  A model doesn’t have to do this, of course!  But if it doesn’t, the model is either too sketchy/incomplete to judge its locality, or else it's complete and there’s just a big empty set for the variables $\lambda$ (maybe there’s nothing “real” in region $\Lambda$, perhaps).  More on this case below.
Bell’s Theorem concerns all possible deeper-level models $P_{a,b,c}(A,B,\lambda)$.  It makes assumptions about such models and then proves a contradiction with experiment.
Enter step (1) of Bell’s Theorem.  The assumptions needed to prove the CHSH inequality are Bell’s Screening Assumption (BSA) and Statistical Independence (SI).  I’ll take them one at a time.
Bell’s Screening Assumption (BSA):  Full knowledge of $\lambda$ is just as informative about region 1 as is knowing the values in both $\lambda$ and region 2.  (and vice-versa).  So, BSA corresponds to the equations:
$P_{a,b,c}(A|B,\lambda) = P_{a,c}(A|\lambda) $
and vice-versa:
$P_{a,b,c}(B|A,\lambda) = P_{b,c}(B|\lambda) $
BSA is Bell’s precise definition of “locality”.   If BSA isn’t true, then even if you already know all about $\lambda$, learning something about region 2 can tell you something about region 1 that you didn’t already know.  Perhaps there’s been some sort of magic nonlocal or faster-than-light connection from “2” to “1”, bypassing the spacetime region $\Lambda$.  Maybe this happens via a Hilbert-space wavefunctions.  But if it happens, however it happens, this is “nonlocal” behavior, by definition.  That’s what nonlocality means in this context: violating the above equations.   (Dreaming up some other definition for locality, like “you can’t signal faster than light”, is fine, I suppose, but it’s not the “locality” ruled out by Bell’s Theorem.  And it’s confusing, to have so many definitions of locality flying around, when we’re talking about this particular context.)
We’re not done yet; you can’t prove any interesting inequalities from BSA alone.  You also need SI:
Statistical Independence (SI):  Future settings can’t be correlated with past variables.  Sometimes called “no-retrocausality”.  Specifically, in this case:
$P_{a,b,c}(\lambda) = P_c(\lambda)$
(because $\lambda$ is in the past of the settings $a,b$, but not $c$.)
Okay, so Bell’s Theorem is the proof that BSA + SI => CHSH inequality, and that inequality is false.  Therefore either BSA is wrong or SI is wrong (or both).  That’s Bell’s Theorem.
Now, the question.   Is there room for a “realism” assumption?  Can you have a “local non-realist” theory which explains the entanglement correlations?  Here are 4 ideas along those lines; of course I’d be happy to consider others.
Idea #1:  What if “realism” is the assumption that there is something in the region $\Lambda$?  Let’s define a non-realistic theory to be one where $\lambda$ is the empty set.  There’s nothing there.
Implication:  If $\Lambda$ is the empty set, then BSA is provably false.  The right side of those equations is just the marginal probabilities measured by Alice and Bob.  And the left side is clearly more informative than the right; knowing the distant setting and results gives us more information about the local results.  Since BSA is violated, this is “nonlocal”.  There’s no “local-nonrealistic” option here.
Idea #2: What is realism is the assumption that there is a deeper-level model $P_{a,b,c}(A,B,\lambda)$ in the first place, and a non-realistic theory should just be of the form $P_{a,b,c}(A,B)$?    Well, you can define realism that way, but consider this is no different from idea #1.  $\lambda$ has just disappeared.  BSA fails.  It’s still nonlocal.
Idea #3: Maybe “non-realism” means there are many universes with different outcomes (A,B), so in a non-realist context we shouldn’t even be talking about single outcomes.
Okay, but then you can’t even talk about a model $P_{a,b,c}(A,B)$ in the first place, $\lambda$ or no $\lambda$.  So BSA is still violated!  (Those equations certainly can’t be true if we’re not allowed to talk about outcome probabilities in the first place.). Bell’s “locality” is nowhere to be found in Everett/Many-Worlds.  You could invent some new definition of locality, I suppose, but it woudn’t be the sort of spacetime-based locality we’re familiar with.
Idea #4: What if we define SI to be “realism”?
Well, now there’s something to talk about.  It’s a terrible term to use, I think, for an assumption whose violation looks like:
$P_{a,b,c}(\lambda) \ne P_c(\lambda)$
such that the future settings are correlated with past hidden variables.  That looks like (hidden) retrocausality, not “non-realism”, in my book.  But, sure.  If someone wants to say that violating SI but not BSA is a local non-realist theory in this sense, that’s a linguistic quirk I’d accept.  But I don’t think that a single person in these threads referring to mysterious “local-nonrealist” theories is actually thinking about retrocausality.  I’d be more than happy to hear otherwise.
Final Summary:  Using Bell's precise definition of "locality", there are no local-nonrealist theories by any definition of realism -- except possibly “realism = no retrocausality”.

It seems to me people who reject realism and claim standard quantum theory is local (non-realist local) mean very different thing from Bell's local causality: they do not assume causality at all (since they don't want any hidden variables), instead, they mean interactions in QFT are local in spacetime, that is, they are described by fields whose changes propagate with speed of light. In this sense, there is a non-realist "local" theory violating Bell's inequalities and agreeing with Bell-inspired tests; the orthodox quantum theory. But one must know what "local" means there.

Ken, are you sure you spent enough time on your answer? Just kidding, great answer even though I disagree with some of your wording. Yes, it’s true that Bell’s later work tended to focus on “local causality” and later writers have parsed ideas out such as PI/SI. But the 1964 paper stands as is, even though nobody would use his approach to express the ideas today. In case I had not expressed this previously, I fully support your ideas linking nonrealistic approaches to retrocausality. After all: a future context and only a future context is a part of the statistical predictions of QM.

This is a very good answer, and I largely agree with the opinions expressed here. Two comments, though.

Another word used for models that break SI (separately from retrocausality) is "superdeterminism", which does receive a fair bit of attention, and which I think a fair number of people would be comfortable classing as "non-realism".

Also, there's a third possibility to breaking BSA or SI - maybe the whole formalism based on classical probability theory is inapplicable or misleading, and needs to be replaced (say, with fuzzy logic, or what have you). I do know smart thinkers in the quantum-interpretations game who lean towards that direction. (cf eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293441/how-can-you-be-a-realist-and-not-posit-an-ontological-model).

@EmilioPisanty How can superdeterminism be "non-realism"? It is assuming determinism, in which there are beables (elements of reality) that determine the measurement results, they are just correlated with measurement setting so SI is violated. Hence, superdeterminism is in the realism group.

@EmilioPisanty: Thanks Emilio.  “Superdeterminism” is not just another word for SI-violating models. As the term is widely used, it’s another class of SI-violating models entirely, with a different causal structure (and no retrocausation).  I didn’t address those because my input settings (a,b) can’t have modelled probability distributions.  (See the text just before the figure.)  Any superdeterministic model would remove (a,b) from the inputs, and so would have a different input-output structure from QM, so it’s arguably not even relevant here. (see the linked paper for more discussion)

@DrChinese:  Thanks!  I see your point on Bell 1964.  But on calling retrocausal models "non-realistic", I think that's very counter-productive.  As you probably saw, most attempts to define "realistic" on these pages refer to actual quantities existing before measurement, precisely what block-universe retrocausal models (like my own) attempt to do.  In a retrocausal model there really is some real history that happens!  Calling this "non-realistic" seems wrong, and it would blur it in with all these arguably-incoherent viewpoints about the past (or future) somehow not being properly real.

@KenWharton Stepping into the arena of "retrocausal/block world" concepts, we're in a world that bears no resemblance to our day to day experience. To me, "realism" is simply the idea that particle observables are all well-defined independent of a future measurement context. This is exactly the opposite of orthodox QM and the Uncertainty relations. Since the statistical formula for spin entanglement is a function of a future context, it is difficult to imagine a mechanism filling the past/future gap - as you mention. I've finally convinced myself that QM is neither "realistic" nor "local".


Bell’s Inequality shows us that a local realism model cannot work.

Bell's inequality itself does not show that. Bell-inspired experiments showing violation of such inequality show that.

How can non-realism ALONE (point 2) explain what’s happening to entangled particles correlating over arbitrarily large distances?

One (important) case of non-realism is the orthodox quantum theory, with Bohr's "obscurantist" philosophy, sometimes called the Copenhagen interpretation. This theory predicts frequencies of results of measurements very well, and does not assign properties to system parts before they are measured (they are not considered as part of reality, hence non-realism). So in this theory, as far as measurable manifestations of entanglement go, there is "nothing to explain" (not really true, but you get the point). The whole system is described by quantum state, we know how this state evolves, and we can extract from it predicted frequencies of measurement results. Of course, the theory has unresolved questions, such as the measurement problem, but its view of entanglement is that everything in the theory is fine and no realistic explanation (using additional pre-existing variables in spacetime linked to measurement results - "hidden variables") of it is needed.

Let’s just assume we accept that non-realism is true, QM is fundamentally probabilistic, and particles have no defined state until measured. This alone doesn’t explain how measuring one particle causes a correlation with its pair far away.

It doesn't, but there is no such thing (measurement causing a correlation) in the orthodox theory. In other words, measurement does not "cause a correlation". The correlation is already there in the psi function, before the measurement. If it is caused by something, it is caused by common past of both parts or common thing affecting both parts. In case of spins, the common past is the decay of particle with zero spin projection, and this "causes" the spin projections of the particles coming out of the decay to be correlated.

Point 2 doesn’t allow for the instantaneous correlation of both particles. Yet I read that most physicists prefer the local non-realism interpretation.

Not sure what you mean by "instantaneous correlation of both particles"; if you mean the collapse on measurement causes the correlation, then no, this is not what causes the correlation. The correlation is already in total psi of the super-system, created in the common past. Measurement just prepares new state and obtains its property (spin projection), and when two measurements are compared in many trials, one can detect they are correlated.
The real problem with orthodox theory is why and how the measurement of any part collapses the psi function of the whole super-system. This seems to be a non-local effect, but it isn't non-local in the sense of Bell or relativity, because it is not a real process in spacetime; it is a change of psi function in physicist's mind, or in computer, to reflect new results of measurements, like when changing probability density in probabilistic model of e.g. weather or pollution, to account for new data. The measurement problem is more about how and why the measurement as a physical process is different from other processes that are described by linear Schroedinger equation, why we get definite results despite superpositions; and this remains unresolved.

Entanglement already exists in a state prior to measurement. It is not created by a measurement. Instead, it is always created locally by some nonlinear process or interaction. The entangled particles can then be separated so that there is a large distance between them.
One way to think of non-realism, is as the notion that there does not exist a unique reality. This notion is revealed by the typical expression of an entangled state, consisting of a superposition. For example
$$ |\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|U\rangle_A|V\rangle_B+|V\rangle_A|U\rangle_B) . $$
Each of the terms represents a "reality." When a measurement in the $A$ system produced a result $U$ it implies that the first term represents the pertinent reality, for which the measurement in the $B$ system will produce $V$. At no point did we need to do or assume anything nonlocal.

Measuring something at A and "manifesting" something at B sure sounds nonlocal to me...  :-)  Anyways, we don't have to debate what locality means; the whole premise of the question is Bell's Theorem, and we can just look up the assumptions of the theorem which are associated with "locality" aka "local causality".  Your account here is nonlocal by that definition.

I concede that maths like this might as well be hieroglyphics to me, which means I may be misunderstanding your reply. I understand that entanglement happens locally. It is the measurement and correlation at great distance that appears non-local. Your comment about "unique reality" though makes me think the realism part I'm stuck  on isn't about probability but the many interpretations that exist underpinning it (e.g. Pilot Wave, MWI, Copenhagen, and many more).

"Entanglement ... is always created locally by some nonlinear process or interaction." Without meaning to undercut you for a statement that is often true: This is strictly both theoretically and experimentally false. See for example https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3991 showing remote entanglement swapping with fully independent sources. And note that the swap can be executed after the entangled 1/4 pair (which have never interacted) has already been measured (i.e. via delayed choice).

@DrChinese: entanglement swapping is produced by a joint measurement that is performed locally. In that sense it is not created non-locally.

@KenWharton: if you read the paper where Bell introduces the inequality you'll see that he discusses locality in the context of special relativity. It is exactly in that sense that I discuss locality. There is no "spooky action at a distance" in my explanation.

@flippiefanus Not sure what local measurement you refer to, since the entangled components are distant from the Bell State Measurement - and that can even be performed after the entangled particles cease to exist. Perhaps your concept of “local” is different than the scientists doing these experiments. Also: Bell doesn’t mention relativity in his 1964 paper. Special relativity has absolutely no bearing on entanglement. (The speed of light does have some bearing of course.) Again: there is no requirement that entangled particles ever exist or interact in a common light cone.


Let’s just assume we accept that non-realism is true, QM is fundamentally probabilistic, and particles have no defined state until measured. This alone doesn’t explain how measuring one particle causes a correlation with its pair far away.

Non-realism as you have stated it doesn't explain why quantum theory is local. All that is required for the restrictions of Bell's theorem to hold is that the measured quantity has a single value at the time of measurement.
However, the idea that a system is described by a single number when it has been measured requires a modification of quantum theory to include collapse such as spontaneous collapse theory:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
These theories can't currently reproduce many of the experimentally tested predictions of quantum theory
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
Quantum theory without such modifications describes the evolution of physical systems with matrices called observables not with random numbers. Lack of interference in everyday life is explained because copying information out of an interfering system suppresses interference - this is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
not by collapse.
In entanglement experiments, information about correlations is carried as quantum information that doesn't change the expectation values of the system carrying that information: locally inaccessible quantum information. This information can be extracted only by doing a comparison with the results of measurements between the members of an entangled pair and the correlation is established by local interactions when the comparison is done and not before:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223
This theory is non-realistic in the sense that an observable doesn't have just a single value before measurement so it is a non-realistic local explanation of entanglement correlations.
