# Psi Ontic interpretations of QM that can be made relativistic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, wavefunction, quantum-interpretations

What Psi [Ontic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontic) interpretations of QM can be made relativistic? Is the Many Worlds interpretation the only one?

Comment: What do you want to ask more precisely ? When you say realistic interpretation of QM, you mean what? QM it's already a very self-consistent theory which provides a great number of predictions at a very accurate level. If you consider the QM with its postulates, it is very realistic, even the non relativistic one! When we talk about relativistic QM, you basically consider the same QM, only with a new form in the Hamiltonian and a "slightly bigger" number of components in the state vector (I'm talking about bispinor).

Comment: @RobertPoenaru by realist interpretations, I mean Psi Ontic interpretations. Where the wave function is real

Comment: Any physical and real process which is described by Q.M can be totally described also by Relativistic Q.M. in an equivalent way.

Comment: What do you mean by 'relativistic'? Are you OK with having ontic entities that are nonlocal but non-communicating?

Comment: Relevant question for background: [What are the differences between a $\psi$-epistemic ontological model and a $\psi$-ontic model of quantum mechanics, exactly?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290522/what-are-the-differences-between-a-psi-epistemic-ontological-model-and-a-ps).

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a rather general list question so my answer's fairly short, but no, there are other $\psi$-ontic interpretations that may be made relativistic.

It's obviously less intuitive starting from this approach, and since there isn't a lot of interest in many interpretations (and many are originally derived from the Schrödinger equation), it seems understandable that $\psi$-ontic interpretations often present conceptual issues in regards to relativity - although this is an issue many $\psi$-epistemic interpretations also share outside of those that are a simple tweak to SQM.

That said, Bohmian mechanics is fairly simple to make relativistic - you can essentially replace the SE in Bohm's derivation with the Klein-Gordon equation and you're half of the way there ([Nikolić, 2012](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1992)).

There are relativistic GRW models also, e.g. [Tumulka (2006)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10955-006-9227-3).

[Stanford encyclopedia](https://seop.illc.uva.nl/entries/qm-modal/) also suggests there are various relativistic modal interpretations; but since they largely reference books I don't have access to their cited sources to discuss.

So I hope that answers your question.